# Effective mass tensor calculation by fitting band structure along 3 perpendicular direction, correct or not?

Tags: solid-state-physics, mass

The effective mass of charge carriers is defined as
$$
\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)_{ij} = \frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2E }{\partial k_i \partial k_j}
$$

Considering that at the CBM we have a parabola. Let's say the equation is of the form
$$
E(k_i, k_j) = ak_i^2 + bk_j^2
$$
where a and b are constants. Now in this case all the values where we have $ \frac{\partial^2E }{\partial k_i \partial k_j}_{i\neq j}$ will be equalent to 0. In other words all the off diagonal terms will be 0 and we will have a diagonal matrix for effective mass tensor. And in such a scenerio we can say that the effective mass along our basis vectors is 100% correct. So for this case eigenvectors and basis vectors would overlap.

My main question is if I calculate the effective mass at the CBM along three prependicular directions will the off diagonal elements be 0 or not?? I believe this is what has been done in  this [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jz500480m). Or do I have to calculate the effective mass tensor and then determine the eigen vectors.

Furthermore if anyone could recommend a good text for effective mass tensors basics that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in general the off-diagonal parts of the tensor are not zero. They are *only* zero if you express the tensor in the basis of its eigenvectors. The safest way to do the calculation is always to calculate the tensor, and determine the eigenvectors.

I wrote a more general discussion about the effective mass tensor on the Matter Modeling SE site [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9566/how-does-one-decide-the-directions-in-which-they-will-calculate-effective-mass/), but I will answer your specific concerns here.

#### 2D example

Let us consider your 2D example, i.e.

$$
E(k_x,k_y) = ak_x^2 + bk_y^2\tag{1}
$$
and let us assume that $a\neq b$ (since otherwise it is degenerate, so any vector would be an eigenvector). If we set $k_y=0$ and sample along $k_x$ then we see:
$$
E(k_x,0) = ak_x^2, \tag{2}
$$
so we can indeed infer $a$ and, hence, the effective mass is $\frac{1}{a}$ in this direction (in atomic units).

Similarly, sampling along $k_y$ would give
$$
E(0,k_y) = bk_y^2, \tag{3}
$$
which also tells us the value of $b$, and hence $\frac{1}{b}$ is the effective mass in this direction. However, this only works because we *know* what the eigenvectors are in this case, and have sampled along them. In general, we do *not* know the eigenvectors, and so this approach will not work.

To illustrate the problem, let us consider sampling along the alternative orthogonal directions:
$$
\vec{k_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
k
\end{array}\right)
~\mathrm{and}
~\vec{k_2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k\\
-k
\end{array}\right)
$$
Now we have,
$$
E(\vec{k_1}) = E\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\right) =a\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)+b\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)= \frac{1}{2}\left(a+b\right)k^2; \tag{4}
$$
thus, sampling along this direction only would lead us to suppose the effective mass is $\frac{2}{\left(a+b\right)}$.

Similarly, sampling in the $\vec{k_2}$ direction leads us to
$$
E(\vec{k_2}) = E\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\right) =a\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)+b\left(\frac{k^2}{2}\right)= \frac{1}{2}\left(a+b\right)k^2, \tag{5}
$$
which also gives an apparent effective mass of $\frac{2}{\left(a+b\right)}$.

#### Alternative viewpoint

Another way of looking at this, is to first write down the general parabolic energy form:
$$
E(k_x,k_y) = ak_x^2 + bk_y^2 + ck_xk_y, \tag{6}
$$
where we now have the extra "cross term". Let us sample *this* along the original $(k_x,0)$ and $(0,k_y)$ directions.

If we set $k_y$ to zero and sample by varying $k_x$, we obtain:
$$
E(k_x,0) = ak_x^2, \tag{7}
$$
which is *exactly the same* as expression (2), even though this is *not* the same parabola, and $a$ is *not* the reciprocal of the effective mass eigenvalue.

Similarly, setting $k_x=0$ and sampling along $k_y$ leads to
$$
E(0,k_y) = bk_y^2, \tag{8}
$$
which is exactly the same as expression (3), even though $b$ is not a reciprocal eigenvalue of the effective mass tensor either.

Comment: thanks for taking out the time and for the amazing explanation